# Issue with jest and enzyme Expected value to be (using ===):

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I am having a test case, which falls and error provided is:

```
Expected value to be (using ===):
      true
    Received:
      false
```

I do not understand why, the component has property with true false, and the result dom should be correct.

- What could cause the problem?
- How to see what jest and enzyme  is comparing?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import Location from './Location'

describe('A suite', function () {
  it('should render without throwing an error', function () {
    expect(shallow(
      <Location
        id={3067696}
        name='Prague'
        country='CZ'
      />).contains(<li><a>Prague, CZ</a></li>)).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

```js
import React from 'react'

const Location = ({ onLocationClick, id, name, country }) => (
  <li>
    <a onClick={onLocationClick}>{name}, {country}</a>
  </li>
)

export default Location
```

This test case work instead:

```
  it('should render to static HTML', function () {
    expect(render(
      <Location
        id={3067696}
        name='Prague'
        country='CZ'
      />
      ).text()).toEqual('Prague, CZ')
  })
```

When using a debugger I see the tree from enzyme as

```
 <li>
        <a onClick={[undefined]}>
          Prague
          ,
          CZ
        </a>
      </li>
```

Comment: It could be the embedded newlines in the `<Location>` content.

Comment: @Pointy interesting, how to add in my test case the  embedded newlines??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back ticks to render the text in your component to avoid rendering without new lines.  You're also missing a prop when rendering your component which means that the  tag will have an `undefined` onClick attribute attached to it when it's shallow rendered.

The below example solves it the prop issue but you can also get the test to pass if you replace it with `.contains(<li><a onClick={undefined}>Prague, CZ</a></li>)).toBe(true)`. This is only if you don't want to don't pass the `onLocationClick` prop.

A handy tip is that you can debug your shallow rendered components by rendering it out and then attaching .debug() to see why it doesn't match. You can find an example below the 2 code snippets listed to resolve your issue.

```js
describe("Test Suite", () => {
  it("renders", () => {
    expect(shallow(
      <Location
        id={3067696}
        name='Prague'
        country='CZ'
        onLocationClick='test'
      />).contains(<li><a onClick="test">Prague, CZ</a></li>)).toBe(true)
  });
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';

const Location = ({ onLocationClick, id, name, country }) => (
    <li>
        <a onClick={onLocationClick}>{`${name}, ${country}`}</a>
    </li>
);

export default Location;
```

=== Debugging a shallow rendered component

```js
const wrapper = shallow(
  <Location
    id={3067696}
    name='Prague'
    country='CZ'
    onLocationClick='test'
  />
);

console.log(wrapper.debug());
```

Comment: what is best to pass onLocationClick or not in your experience?

Comment: @Radex pass in literally anything you want as it should be a separate test to test whatever you want it to do. I wouldn't leave it undefined though which is why I just passed in some text.

Comment: could you please help me here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133847/enzyme-with-jest-issue-with-expectreceived-tobeexpected