# enzyme with jest - Issue with expect(received).toBe(expected)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have an issue to validate this test case using jest and enzyme.
Basically, the event handler create an error:

`Issue with expect(received).toBe(expected)`

If I remove the events handlers test case pass.
If you look at the result of function `.debug` I see in the eventhandler a function.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Any explanation thanks!

```js
import React from 'react'
// import { render, mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import LocationFinderSearch from './LocationFinderSearch'

describe('<LocationFinderSearch />', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<LocationFinderSearch />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(shallow(
      <LocationFinderSearch
        onLocationChange='test'
        onSearchClick='test'
      />
    ).contains(
      <form>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Location' onChange='test' />
        <input type='submit' value='Search' />
      </form>
        )).toBe(true)
  })
```

```js
import React from 'react'

const LocationFinderSearch = ({ onLocationChange, onSearchClick, inputValue }) => (
  <form>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Location' onChange={(e) => onLocationChange(e)} />
    <input type='submit' value='Search' onClick={(e) => onSearchClick(e, inputValue)} />
  </form>
)

export default LocationFinderSearch
```

Logs from `.debug()`

```js
 console.log src\forecast\locationFinder\LocationFinderSearch.test.js:9
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Location" onChange={[Function]} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
```

Comment: You pass string ('test') to as event handler?

Comment: yes, maybe is wrong, what should i pass instead?

Comment: Try a noop function ()={} instead, and don't test how it renders, users don't see callbacks, test how it behaves using spy/mock.